# Where can I get the Stack Overflow logo with minimum 300 DPI?

Tags: support, logo

How can I get the Stack Overflow logo with minimum 300 DPI resolution?

Comment: You could make it yourself in Photoshop. SO is an extremely simple logo.

Comment: @user145576 : what pixel size do you need? I could probably quickly make one in Photoshop. :D

Answer (score 3):

We generally don't provide such detailed images, but I believe there are some resources on Stack Apps

[SVG Versions of the Logos](https://stackapps.com/questions/347/svg-versions-of-the-logos)

Comment: Great. Now I can make a fortune selling StockOverflew t-shirts!

Comment: @Jesse, and then lose a fortune on the lawsuit.